# Where would an authentication model fit in the MVC framework?

Tags: model-view-controller

Suppose my module accepts a username and password and returns true or false to indicate success or failure.  Would this be more a model or a controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really doesn't need to exist in a controller. It could be in a class library if needed. You would need to have a Controller Action / View that eventually prompts a user for their credentials, but the logic of authenticating does not need to exist in the Controller Action.

Answer (score 2):

The username, password and success indicator would be part of the Model,

the model would be made visible to the client in the View,

the model would be processed by the Controller.

Answer (score 1):

Authentication is a service - structure from model layer, which utilizes both domain object and data storage structure (usually data mappers). As minimum, it has to interact with `User` domain objects and both persistent storage (like SQL) and cookies. It also might require data exchange with session.

Also, when controller sends user login details to model layer, it should not receive any replay. That part should be handles by the current View, which requests the user-state from model layer.

**P.S.** I hope you are not one of the people who refer to IE as "the internet" and ASP.NET MVC framework as "the MVC".

Answer (score 0):

it will be an action from a controller.